# SMS notification when selected friends are online

Tags: facebook, sms

I have an idea to develop a Facebook app which notifies the user through SMS when his/her friends come online. The user can pre-select the friends he/she wanted to get SMS notifications of.

This is my first attempt at developing for Facebook so I have zero experience and knowledge about the platform. I just want to know if my idea for such an app is possible? Does Facebook have an API for SMSes? Or do they let 3rd party messaging APIs (such as [this](http://www.twilio.com/api/sms) one I came across) to work with them.

Thank you.

Comment: Trying to stalk your crush(es)? :p

Comment: @ThiefMaster haha...you read my mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

A Facebook app is actually ran off of your server and you can do anything that you want as long as you stay inside the limits of what you requested as far as information the app needs. As far and getting the information it is relatively easy. I made a extremely complicated app in 3 days. Once you read and get how to pull certain information, the rest is cake walk

Comment: I see. Going through their documentation seems like a good start. Thank you.